# JModelList Group by Category

Tags: development, mvc, database, model, joomla-3.3.x

I have a Component with the following table:

```
+------------------+------------------+------+-----+---------------------+----------------+
| Field            | Type             | Null | Key | Default             | Extra          |
+------------------+------------------+------+-----+---------------------+----------------+
| id               | int(11) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL                | auto_increment |
| asset_id         | int(10) unsigned | NO   |     | 0                   |                |
| title            | varchar(255)     | NO   |     | NULL                |                |
| file             | varchar(255)     | NO   |     | NULL                |                |
| category         | int(11)          | NO   |     | NULL                |                |
| ordering         | int(11)          | NO   |     | NULL                |                |
| state            | tinyint(1)       | NO   |     | NULL                |                |
| checked_out      | int(11)          | NO   |     | NULL                |                |
| checked_out_time | datetime         | NO   |     | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 |                |
| created_by       | int(11)          | NO   |     | NULL                |                |
+------------------+------------------+------+-----+---------------------+----------------+
```

I am using JCategories. Here is my current model File:

```
<?php

/**
 * @version     1.0.0
 * @package     com_media_centre
 * @copyright   Copyright (C) 2014. All rights reserved.
 * @license     GNU General Public License version 2 or later; see LICENSE.txt
 * @author      Dawid van der Hoven <dawid@jamfactory.co.za> - http://www.jamfactory.co.za
 */
defined('_JEXEC') or die;

jimport('joomla.application.component.modellist');

/**
 * Methods supporting a list of Media_centre records.
 */
class MediaModelFiles extends JModelList {

    /**
     * Constructor.
     *
     * @param    array    An optional associative array of configuration settings.
     * @see        JController
     * @since    1.6
     */
    public function __construct($config = array()) {
        parent::__construct($config);
    }

    /**
     * Method to auto-populate the model state.
     *
     * Note. Calling getState in this method will result in recursion.
     *
     * @since   1.6
     */
    protected function populateState($ordering = null, $direction = null) {

        // Initialise variables.
        $app = JFactory::getApplication();

        // List state information
        $limit = $app->getUserStateFromRequest('global.list.limit', 'limit', $app->getCfg('list_limit'));
        $this->setState('list.limit', $limit);

        $limitstart = JFactory::getApplication()->input->getInt('limitstart', 0);
        $this->setState('list.start', $limitstart);


        if(empty($ordering)) {
            $ordering = 'a.ordering';
        }

        // List state information.
        parent::populateState($ordering, $direction);
    }

    /**
     * Build an SQL query to load the list data.
     *
     * @return  JDatabaseQuery
     * @since   1.6
     */
    protected function getListQuery() {
        // Create a new query object.
        $db = $this->getDbo();
        $query = $db->getQuery(true);

        // Select the required fields from the table.
        $query->select(
                $this->getState(
                        'list.select', 'a.*'
                )
        );

        $query->from('`#__media_files` AS a');


    // Join over the users for the checked out user.
    $query->select('uc.name AS editor');
    $query->join('LEFT', '#__users AS uc ON uc.id=a.checked_out');

        // Join over the category 'category'
        $query->select('category.title AS category_title');
        $query->join('LEFT', '#__categories AS category ON category.id = a.category');
        // Join over the created by field 'created_by'
        $query->select('created_by.name AS created_by');
        $query->join('LEFT', '#__users AS created_by ON created_by.id = a.created_by');


        // Filter by search in title
        $search = $this->getState('filter.search');
        if (!empty($search)) {
            if (stripos($search, 'id:') === 0) {
                $query->where('a.id = ' . (int) substr($search, 3));
            } else {
                $search = $db->Quote('%' . $db->escape($search, true) . '%');
                $query->where('( a.title LIKE '.$search.' )');
            }
        }



        //Filtering category
        $filter_category = $this->state->get("filter.category");
        if ($filter_category) {
            $query->where("a.category = '".$filter_category."'");
        }

        return $query;
    }

    public function getItems() {
        return parent::getItems();
    }

}
```

Okay Now the actual question:

How can I return data in a format like:

```
Category 1 (and the alternative layout param)
 - Item in Category 1
 - Item in Category 1
 - Item in Category 1

Category 2 (and the alternative layout param)
 - Item in Category 2
 - Item in Category 2
 - Item in Category 2
```

I apologize its not in the scope or if its to heavy of a question, If it is just drop a comment and ill remove, otherwise please let me know if any other information is required.

Comment: Is this a sql query issue?

Comment: I dont think so..

Answer (score 2):

I do not know if this is possible using SQL, but you can get such result using PHP:

```
$byCategory = array();

foreach ($items as $item)
{
    if (empty($byCategory[$item->category_title]))
    {
            $byCategory[$item->category_title] = array();
    }
    $byCategory[$item->category_title][] = $item;
}
```

`$byCategory` array will have the data sorted as you have described:

```
Array
(
    [Category 1] => Array
        (
            [0] => stdClass Object
                (
                    Item in Category 1
                )

            [1] => stdClass Object
                (
                    Item in Category 1
                )

            [2] => stdClass Object
                (
                    Item in Category 1
                )
        )

    [Category 2] => Array
        (
            [0] => stdClass Object
                (
                    Item in Category 2
                )

            [1] => stdClass Object
                (
                    Item in Category 2
                )

            [2] => stdClass Object
                (
                    Item in Category 2
                )
        )
)
```

Comment: I think your right, multi level arrays were never made for mysql, so its best to logically split them from the array given by mysql.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using PDO, you can fetch using key-pairs methods, I'm not extremely experienced with PDO + Joomla, but in pure PDO you can do something like this:

```
$q = $db->query("SELECT `category_title` AS name, `value` AS value FROM `wherever`;");
$r  = $q->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_KEY_PAIR);
```

Then it will group them as key => value, you can also write something like "$sth->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC | PDO::FETCH_GROUP, 2)" to fetch them as groups.

http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.constants.php
Search for "FETCH_" and you can see a set of fetch methods.

It might not answer your question entirely, but hopefully wake some ideas on how to solve your problem.